# Is there a Stack Exchange site for motivation?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I would like to know whether there is a Stack Exchange site for discussion on motivational (motivating oneself and others) topics. If yes please point me to it. And if not, why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) could be the site you are looking for.

Depending on your exact question it will fit there or not, so make sure to check their help center or meta before asking.

Comment: Looks like the site no longer exists :(